# Can neutral cards be used as a resource?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-lcg

Very straightforward question, can neutral cards be added to a domain as a resource?

I can't seem to find anything that says you cant, but just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them to the domain as a resource.  You do need at least one card from a non-neutral card's faction in order to pay for that card though.

http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/612548/playing-neutral-card-domain-question